# How I convert CURL command to PHP?

Tags: php, curl

Hello I have command in CURL

```
curl –k –H "Content-Type:application/json" –d "{\"api_key\":\"123456789\"}" –X GET "https://1.1.1.1:7777/auth"
```

which returns

```
{"Token":"ABC123"}
```

How can convert this command in php ?

```
$ch = curl_init('https://1.1.1.1:7777/auth');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
   'Content-Type: application/json',
   'Authorization: Bearer ' . 123456789
   ));
$token = curl_exec($ch);
echo $token;
```

I try this , but not works

Comment: What does "not works" mean? What is the result, what error do you see?

Comment: @OlajosCs well to me it's obvious that he didn't translate `–X GET` and didn't translate `–d "{\"api_key\":\"123456789\"}"`

Answer (score 1):

In order for CURL to work, you need to initialize your session first so:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://1.1.1.1:7777/auth");
/*CURL OPTIONS*/
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

If you're passing your api key as a post parameter, your curl options should probably look something like:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode(['api_key'=>"123456789"]));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,['Content-Type: application/json']);
```

Comment: you got 2 things wrong, 1: `-x GET` translates to CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST `GET` not `POST`. 2: you gave POSTFIELDS an array, that means the data will be sent in the `multipart/form-data` format, NOT json-format. to send json, you must set POSTFIELDS to a string - the json-string. the correct translation would be ```curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode(['api_key'=>"123456789"]));```

Comment: You're right, I didn't pay attention to that. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is solution:

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
  $headers = array();
  $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(['api_key'=>"123456789"]));
```

Comment: looks correct to me :)  btw it will look prettier + more maintainable if you do ```curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode(['api_key'=>"123456789"]));```